# Angular2: How to bind the currency pipe currency

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

How do you bind to the currency field in Angular2?

If I have a table of data:

Currency | Amount | Desired Result

USD      | 12,000 | $12,000

EUR      | 10,000 | €10,000

I know the standard formatting pipe: 
{{ item.Amount | currency:'EUR':true:'1.2-2'}}

But I can't seem to do this dynamically?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by `dynamically` in this scenario?

Comment: So I'm iterating through a table of data and want to display the correct currency symbol for each row

Comment: Have you try this `{{ item.Amount | currency: item.Currency :true:'1.2-2'}}`

Comment: I just tried the above from William and it works great!

Comment: @WilliamHan thats great thanks, I thought I tried that and it didn't work but it turns out I have a temperamental side issue when sometimes saved changes don't appear in the browser!

Nice and simple. Can I mark comments as answers?